# Input and output comma separated list from/to textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, csv

I have an array similar to this:

```
list = {
  cat: "dog",
  rain: "sun",
  baby: "adult"
};
```

I have 2 textboxes.

If I type a list separated by comma into one textbox like this:

**cat, rain, baby**

and press a button, how can I get the paired values in the same comma separated list in another textbox like this?:

**dog, sun, adult**

**Edit:** Additional optional question - is it also possible to include other text not in the array but still parse for the ones in the array? For example, if I type "hug my cute cat", it outputs "hug my cute dog", etc.

Any clue/direction would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Could you rephrase that in the form of a question?

Comment: @user978122 Sure, sorry, I just wanted to make things clear by listing the prob in steps but it does seem kind of confusing. I edited it a bit -- hope that's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var inputs  = userText.split(",");
        var output = [];
        while(inputs.length){
            var key  = inputs.shift();
            if(list[key]){
                output.push(list[key]);           
            }
        }
        alert(output.join(","));
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6Mn5V/1/